# BBQ chicken and burger patty too dry

Tags: cooking-time, barbecue

I m not an expert at BBQ but last time I made them, 2 things happened. When they were looking juicy and cooked from outside, when checked from inside they were still raw but after cooking for a while, they were slightly black/burned and were dried.

I was using charcoal grill and I used 2 packets of [BBQuick lumpwood](https://www.barbequick.com/grillguide/product/4-5kg-lumpwood-x8-bags/) and stainless steel

[image]

I started BBQing when they were almost red and white colour

What could I be doing wrong and how to make my BBQ juicy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using a lower temperature/lower fire.  It sounds like the outside overcooked before the inside was done.  Plus, if you are using metal skewers (pictured) they will conduct heat to the inside fairly quickly.  It wouldn't take long to go from under to overcooked over very hot coals.

Comment: How to find out if chicken, burger patty are cooked on right temperature and not undercooked?

Comment: @localhost use a probe thermometer, be sure to factor in carry-over cooking.

Comment: What is carry-over cooking?

Comment: @localhost https://www.recipetips.com/glossary-term/t--38606/carryover-cooking.asp

Answer (score 2):

The grill you have is more like a hibachi than the more usual grill used in the US.

It will cook very hot because the food is so close to the coals. It will work well for things like Indonesian-style skewers, where the meat is cut fairly thin to avoid the problem you had: scorched outside before the inside is cooked.

To cook thicker pieces of meat, you'll want a grill that allows you to raise the meat further above the coals, giving a lower cooking temperature. If you use a grill with a cover, you also use more ambient heat for cooking rather than direct (radiated) heat.

Comment: Doesn't higher raise mean longer cooking time?

Comment: @localhost, sure. The other option is to cut your meat into thinner cuts appropriate for a hibachi.